# tcl regexp with with paren-delimited groups

Tags: regex, tcl, match

I have a group of strings that look like:

```
foo<xyz><123>
bar
pizza<oregano><tomato><mozzarella>
```

so is boils down to a prefix (`foo`, `bar`, `pizza`,...) followed by any number of attribute names inclosed in angled brackets.
both the prefix and the attributes may consist of any character with the exception of angled brackets (which are only used for *delimiting* the attribute names)
Neither prefix nor attribute names must be empty.

Now I would like to have a regex in my Tcl application, that gives me both the prefix and all the attributes (it's ok if they keep their delimiting brackets, though i the end I have to split them up into a *list*).

The trivial approach `^(.+)(<.+>)*$` doesn't work because the trailing `.+` is too greedy and eats away all the matches for the attribute names.

So I tried excluding the forbidden angle brackets `^(\[^<>\]+)(<.+>)*$` which works OK at first glance - but then i discovered that this would match `fnork<<>><x<>>` violating the rule that attribute names must not contain any angular brackets (apart from the delimiting one).

Third, I extended the forbidden characters to the attribute names `^(\[^<>\]+)(<\[^<>\]>)*$`, but now things are getting a bit shady: while the regex only matches valid strings (so both prefix and attribute names must not contain any brackets), i no longer get the attribute names in as a match part:

```
% regexp -all -inline "^(\[^<>\]+)(<\[^<>\]+>)*" "A<xyz><123>"
A<xyz><123> A <123>
```

For whatever reason the `<xyz>` is not returned!

Any idea how to fix this?

### side-note

the actual string I'm trying to parse uses square brackets and parentheses as delimiters. something like:  `pizza[large](tomato)(olives)(cheese)` where there `[term]` can appear 0 or 1 time, whereas the `(term)`s can appear 0 or more times.
but due to the nature of square brackets and parentheses this requires a fair amount of quoting, which is probably too much of a distraction to be useful here)

Comment: If you want to split the second capture as Step 2, all you need is to use a capturing group around the second quantified group - `"^([^<>]+)((?:<[^<>]+>)*)"`. Please watch out for formatting issues when using built-in formatting tools: SO often adds backslashes before square brackets.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/7wMO28, with `{^([^<>]+)((?:<[^<>]+>)*)$}` regex, is it working well enough?

Comment: I definitely advise putting Tcl REs in curly braces if you can; it avoids all the problems with excessive backslashes (otherwise a major problem with complex REs) and almost all REs are suitable for that treatment.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew perfect. since you haven't posted an answer i've accepted the one by DonalFellows which is practically identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, the trick is to use a fairly simple RE and post-process the results:

```
% regexp -all -inline {^([^<>]+)((?:<[^<>]+>)*)$} foo<xyz><123>
foo<xyz><123> foo <xyz><123>
% regexp -all -inline {[^<>]+} <xyz><123>
xyz 123
```

You were almost there, but were struggling with using `(<[^<>]+>)*`, which won't work as that only captures the group *one of the times it matches.* (I wasn't aware that it captured the last match, but since I rarely want either first or last but rather all, I use a different approach.)

Putting that all together and assuming you've got one big multi-line string that has all the pieces you want to look at in it (e.g., because you've read it from a file) you get:

```
set str "foo<xyz><123>
bar
pizza<oregano><tomato><mozzarella>"

# Find the matching lines and do the first-level extract on them
foreach {- prefix attribs} [regexp -all -line -inline {^([^<>]+)((?:<[^<>]+>)*)$} $str] {
    # Split the attribute names
    set attributes [regexp -all -inline {[^<>]+} $attribs]
    # Show that we've matched them for real
    puts "prefix='$prefix', attributes=[join $attributes ,]"
}
```

Which produces this output:

```
prefix='foo', attributes=xyz,123
prefix='bar', attributes=
prefix='pizza', attributes=oregano,tomato,mozzarella
```

Comment: Doing things in several steps is often a lot simpler than trying to do it all in one gigantic single step, and isn't necessarily much slower either. (The one bit of syntax you weren't already using is the non-capturing parentheses, `(?:…)`, which makes writing these sorts of things much easier.)

Answer (score 1):

Let's tokenize this.

```
package require string::token

set lex {[[] LB []] RB [(] LP [)] RP [^][()]+ t}
set str {pizza[large](tomato)(olives)(cheese)}

% set tokens [::string::token text $lex $str]
{t 0 4} {LB 5 5} {t 6 10} {RB 11 11} {LP 12 12} {t 13 18} {RP 19" 19} {LP 20 20} {t 21 26} {RP 27 27} {LP 28 28} {t 29 34} {RP 35 35}
```

Having tokenized, we can parse, or evaluate the tokens as statements in a little language:

```
% set terms [lassign $tokens prefix]

proc t {str beg end} {
    string range $str $beg $end
}
proc LB {str beg end} {
    return "Optional term is: "
}
proc RB args {
    return \n
}
proc LP {str beg end} {
    rename LP {}
    proc LP args {
        return ", "
    }
    return "Arguments are: "
}
proc RP args {}

% puts "Prefix is: [eval [linsert $prefix 1 $str]]"
Prefix is: pizza
% % join [lmap term $terms {eval [linsert $term 1 $str]}] {}
Optional term is: large
Arguments are: tomato, olives, cheese
```

Documentation:
[eval](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/eval.htm),
[join](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/join.htm),
[lassign](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lassign.htm),
[linsert](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/linsert.htm),
[lmap (for Tcl 8.5)](http://wiki.tcl.tk/40570),
[lmap](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lmap.htm),
[package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm),
[proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm),
[puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm),
[rename](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/rename.htm),
[return](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/return.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[string::token (package)](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/string/token.html)

Answer (score 0):

I might have misread the requirements, but given that you have already "encoded" all structural details in your ad hoc notation, why not have the Tcl list machinery do the work?

```
set str {foo(xyz)(123)
bar
pizza[large](oregano)(tomato)(mozzarella)}

foreach line [split $str \n] {
    set line [string map {"[" " " "]" " " ")(" " " "(" " {" ")" "} "} $line]
    set suffix [lassign $line prefix]
    lassign $suffix a b
    if {[llength $suffix] == 2} {
      set optional $a
      set attributes $b
    } else {
      set optional ""
      set attributes $a
    }
    puts "prefix='$prefix', optional='$optional', attributes='[join $attributes ,]'"
}
```

I apologise, strictly speaking, my answer does not address the regex question. And there is less wizardy than in the other replies ;)

Comment: This is an exercise sometimes referred to as TEXTUAL POLISHING. Obviously, well-formedness checks are out of reach, beyond testing the list property of the `string map` result or for expected arities of sub-lists etc.

Comment: hmm, what if the any of the delimted words contain spaces? Then you get too many words. What if there is an unmatched open brace? Then you have an invalid list.

Comment: "words contain spaces" can be addressed by an extra (inner) level of curly bracing: `{"[" " " "]" " " ")(" "\} \{" "(" " \{\{" ")" "\}\} "}`. this is fine, as in Tcl, there is no difference between an atom and a one-element list. an "invalid list" can be trapped with a `string is list` check, which should be just fine, given that the requirement stated that the result of processing should be a list anyways.

Comment: this is not to say that a regex or a tokenizer would not be more robust, I said so in my earlier comment.

Comment: thanks for the idea. however, in my case the actual strings i want to parse are "user input", so i cannot really rely on well-formedness (though i didn't say that in my question)